# Reading MSG file from outlook via powershell .. how to get email address?

Tags: powershell, com, outlook, msg

Fairly simple script at the moment I simply need to get the recipients email address out of a msg file, apparently there's not an easy way to parse it in text so I've used the following code, but I only get a name such as 'Joe Smith' when reading the message not joe.smith@mydomain.com

Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
$outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$msg = $outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("c:\MyMessage.msg")
$msg | Select to
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the Recipients collection and read the Recipient.Address property for the items in that collection. You also might want to use Application.Session.OpenSharedItem instead of CreateItemFromTemplate.

Comment: thanks, whats the difference between openshareditem and createitemfromtemplate?

Comment: CreateItemFromTemplate creates a new message based on the template, but it wipes out quite a few properties, such as anything sender related.